# Why and When is polymorphism used to point a base class to a derived class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Assume the following code:

```
class base {
public:
 int getAge(){
  return 20;
 }
};

class dri : public base {
public:
 int getAge(){
  return 30;
 }
};

int main(){

 base *b = new dri();
 std::cout << b->getAge() << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

I know with the magic of polymorphism the above code is compiled and you will get `20` in your console, you can also override them using the `virtual` keyword.

My question is, why and when would you use this? if you need an object of type `dri` why won't you just do `dri d;` or `dri *d = new dri()`, since it already includes all the functionalities of `base`.

Comment: You could make a vector of `base *`, and store both `base` and `dri` instances in it. E.g. if you were making a game, you could make all enemy classes derived from a single base, and store them all in a single `vector`.

Comment: Polymorphism is a way to reuse code.  Let's say you have a data consumer which is fed data from a text file comma-separated value (CSV) parser.  Later, you instead have an SQLite backend, so you pass in the different SQL parser to the data consumer.  The data consumer code does not have to change AT ALL even though it was created back in the day where there was only a CSV parser.  The hard part is knowing when to abstract out an interface, and when not to over engineer a solution.

Comment: Just think of any example where you have several classes that derives from the base one. You base class could be "vehicle" and your derived classes could be "car", "truck" or "motorcycle". They all have need to have a method "startupRoutine()" but their implementations will all be different. Your base class can hold a "default" implementation or may not even if the method is pure virtual.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `dri`, then just go ahead and declare your variable as such.

The benefit of polymorphism is that if all you need are the methods that are defined on `base`, then you can define your variable (or most likely, function parameter) as `base *` (or `base &`) and your code will work with any class derived from `base` including `dri`.

If there are only two classes in your system (`base` and `dri`) then it's difficult to see the benefits. But imagine that the base class is something more general like `DataSource` and it has a method called `readData`. Now you can write code that reads data from a source without having to worry that data source is a `Database` or a `Keyboard` or `Sensor` or anything else. You can write the data-handling logic and someone else can come along later and add new sources by creating new `DataSource` subclasses.

In order for this to work, the methods involved have to be `virtual`. If you define a non-virtual `base` method and call it with a `base` pointer or reference, you'll always get that function, even if a subclass tries to override it. The `virtual` keyword tells C++ to call the method defined for the the actual object type rather than the declared variable type.